# Búsqueda incremental

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Estoy implementando una búsqueda incremental en PHP. El problema es que, si hago la *query* para que me devuelva **todos** los registros, tarda un momento. Si, durante ese tiempo, el usuario *modifica* los parámetros de búsqueda (teclea alguna letra mas), PHP sigue *a su bola*. Aunque *cancele* la petición AJAX, la *query* sigue en marcha.

La base de datos tiene, mas o menos, esta estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE parts(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  barcode TEXT,
  code TEXT NOT NULL,
  desc TEXT,
  notes TEXT
);
```

Como motor de base de datos, estoy usando SQLite. Por diversos motivos, **no** se puede usar otro.

En la documentación de PHP, se indica la función [connection_aborted( )](http://php.net/manual/es/function.connection-aborted.php)

```
int connection_aborted ( void )
```

Esta función tiene ciertas *peculiaridades*: comprueba la conexión **al enviar algo** al navegador. Si PHP está esperando el resultado de la *query*, es inútil para mis propósitos.

Por lo tanto, la única solución que se me ocurre es realizar la *query* para que no me devuelva **toda** la lista, sino tan solo cierta cantidad de filas.

Así pues, si tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE desc LIKE '%texto_tecleado_por_usuario%'
```

¿ Como la modifico para que me devuelva los resultados de 100 en 100 filas en sucesivas consultas ?

- Primera consulta: las 100 primeras.
- Segunda consulta: las 100 siguientes.
- Tercera consulta: las 100 siguientes.
- ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para paginar el resultado de una consulta podes usar las clausulas `LIMIT` y `OFFSET` (opcional) en conjunto con `ORDER BY` en la consulta `SELECT`.

### LIMIT

La cláusula `LIMIT` es usada para limitar la cantidad de registros devueltos en una consulta `SELECT`. Existen 2 sintaxis distintas, y ambas devuelven el mismo resultado.

[Documentación (en inglés)](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset)

#### LIMIT solo

Recibe uno o dos argumentos.

Si usamos LIMIT **con un sólo argumento**, estaremos seleccionando sólamente los `N` primeros elementos de nuestra tabla.

```
// Devuelve el primer registro
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT 1

// Devuelve los primeros 100 registros
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT 100
```

*Por defecto el registro inicial es `0`, es decir, `0` equivale al primer registro de la tabla.*

Si usamos LIMIT **con dos argumentos**, el primer argumento especifica el primer registro a devolver y el segundo la cantidad total de registros a devolver.

```
// Devuelve 10 registros de la tabla, empezando por el tercero e ignorando los dos primeros
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT 2,10
```

#### LIMIT + OFFSET

La cláusula opcional `OFFSET` es usada para definir los primeros `N` registros que van a ser omitidos en la consulta `SELECT`.

```
// Devuelve 10 registros de la tabla, empezando por el tercero e ignorando los dos primeros
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2
```

Para evitar confusiones, se recomienda el uso de esta sintaxis en vez de utilizar la clausula `LIMIT` con el `OFFSET` separado por una coma (`LIMIT x, y`).

#### Equivalencias

Esta consulta

```
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT <devolver> OFFSET <omitir>
```

es equivalente a

```
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT <omitir>, <devolver>
```

lo único que cambia es la sintaxis.

[Respuesta original en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query)

### ORDER BY

La clausula `ORDER BY` define el orden en que van a ser devueltos los registros.

En las bases de datos relaciones los registros (mejor dicho tuplas) no tienen un orden específico, por ello se recomienda el uso de la clausula `ORDER BY` para garantizar de forma explícita que los registros sean devueltos en un orden en particular.

---

**Solución**

Entonces, la primer consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
// Devuelve los primeros 100 registros ordenados por el id.
SELECT * 
FROM parts 
WHERE desc LIKE '%texto_tecleado_por_usuario%' 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 100;
```

La segunda consulta:

```
// Devuelve 100 registros, empezando por el 101 e ignorando los 100 primeros
SELECT * 
FROM parts 
WHERE desc LIKE '%texto_tecleado_por_usuario%' 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100;
```